# How to calculate average in java?

Tags: java, lambda, stream

I'm following a tutorial and I didn't get this part where we get the average of these numbers.
Would you please explain how are these numbers calculated and how do we get **7.5** as result ?

```
//   Finding the average of the numbers squared

    Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4}).map(n -> n * n).average().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

result ->
7.5

Comment: Note that it's the average of the square of each value, since it's doing `.map(n -> n * n)`. That `map()` returns `{1,4,9,16}` and the average of those values is 7.5

Comment: you are squaring the numbers, and then calculate the average of the sum of squares. Just remove the map statement and it would then work. `Arrays.stream(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }).average()`

Comment: What _do_ you get?

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper Thank you. I got the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below the breakdown of what that stream is doing

```
Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4}) //Converts int[] to IntStream
.map(n -> n * n) //Squares each element of the stream, now we have 1, 4, 9, 16
.average() // Calculate average between those numbers, it's 7.5
.ifPresent(System.out::println); //We have an Optional<Double>, if it's present we print it.
```

So this solution is good for you, just have to get rid of `.map(n -> n * n)` to calculate the average of the numbers and not their square.